# Faster approach to load data in NSTableView from a file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my application I am reading data from a text file and displaying it in NSTableView. There are 6 columns in my tableview. My problem is when the records in file are more it takes too long to read and display the data. e.g. It takes around 1 min to read and display 70,000 records from the file. I am using NSArrayController to update my NSTableView. Please suggest some solution to make my application faster. Should I read and display only that much data that is visible to the user (like in iphone but i dont know how is it done OSX?) and update my view on scrolling?

Thanks & Regards
Abhijeet

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use the CoreData framework. Reading in the entire array with 70,000 records is nuts.

Start here: [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075).